# Symfony2 same path differents HTTP Methods

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I'm using angularjs with symfony2. I can't use the same path with a different method.

Angularjs service

```
angular.module('adminApp')
  .service('users', ['$resource', function events($resource) {
   function
    return $resource(Routing.generate('users'), { id: "@_id" }, {
      'create': { method: 'POST' },
      'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
      'update': { method: 'PUT' },
      'delete': { method: 'DELETE'}
    });
  }]);
```

Symfony2 Routing

```
users:
    pattern: /users
    defaults: { _controller: AppAdminBundle:User:list }
    methods:  [GET]
    options:
        expose: true

users:
    pattern: /users
    defaults: { _controller: AppAdminBundle:User:update }
    methods:  [PUT]
    options:
        expose: true
```

User controller

```
public function listAction()
{
    //list
}

public function updateAction()
{
    //update
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I can't"? Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

You have two routes named equally.

Name first as `users_list`, second - `users_update` and it should work fine.

Comment: I now that but my angularjs service only can assign one name.  return $resource(Routing.generate('users'),

Comment: Symfony's internal routing name has nothing to the Angular's resource name. In routes.yml, you have already specified resource name using route pattern. Angular uses "users" variable to generate URL.